# Verifying that task was executed by a specific function

Tags: ios, security, encryption, rsa

I would like to verify that a task, let's say downloading an image from my server, was done by a function in my iOS app. For instance if another client downloads the image, or the client has been tampered with in some way, I should be able to tell.

My initial idea was to have a private key in the function source code and a public key on my server. Then use RSA in some way to make sure the download was done by the function. However, this obviously cannot work since someone could decompile the code and get the private key stored in the source code.

Is there any known way to do this?

Comment: Make a signature on the file with a private key only you have, and use the corresponding public key in the code to verify the downloaded image.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to protect and from whom. Can you describe your issue in more detail? What you're asking about is not possible but perhaps what you're asking about and your actual issue are distinct so that it can be solved in a different way.